# $.ajax works on MAMP/localhost not site server

Tags: php, ajax, recaptcha

Looking for some additional thoughts on where to go with troubleshooting. I have a google noCaptcha reCaptcha on my contact page.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my-site-key" data-callback="onReturnCallback" data-theme="light"></div>
```

On the same page I have the callback script

```
<script type="text/javascript">;
  var onReturnCallback = function(response) {
    console.log('callback');
    var url = '../php/proxy.php?url=' + 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    console.log(url);
    var request = $.ajax({
      'url': url,
      data: {
        response: response
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        var res = data.success.toString();
        if (res === 'true') {
          document.getElementById('g-recaptcha').innerHTML = 'THE CAPTCHA WAS SUCCESSFULLY SOLVED';
          document.getElementById('theButton').removeAttribute('disabled');
          document.getElementById('theButton').innerHTML = 'Submit';
        }
      },
      statusCode: {
        404: function() {
          alert("page not found");
        }
      }
    }); //ajax done

    request.done(function(msg) {
      alert("ajax finished" + msg);
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert("Request failed: " + textStatus)
    });
  }; // end of onReturnCallback

</script>;
```

and in a separate file I have

```
<?php
  if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) {
  header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
  die('You are not allowed to access this file.');
 }
header('Content-type: application/json');
$url=$_GET['url'];
$response=$_GET['response'];
$secret = "my-secret-key";
$params = array('secret'=>$secret, 'response'=>$response);
$json=file_get_contents( $url  . '?secret=' . $secret . '&response=' . $response);
echo $json;
?>
```

This all works out fine on my local MAMP setup. When I transfered it up to the server I'm getting back an alert from request.fail saying that there is a parseerror. Permissions for the proxy.php are 755. I tried removing

```
dataType: 'json'
```

from the request - no change in response. Not sure what else is needed to help out.

Comment: Does the new server address need to be registered to use the recaptcha API ?

Comment: Hmm...I originally registered using the server site. Any key will work locally, but it should spit back a problem with the reCaptcha verify rather than the parseerror if the key is malformed.